# Running out of Gas while deploying contract via web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

```
// contract is storing ABI
 var instance = contract.new(
    "0x12", // bytes32
    "0x12", // bytes32
    [],   // array of addresses
    11,  // uint
    11,  // uint
    "0x0aB245c1d6Da5e7CAe0c9607b5bFA2747574c2b1", // another contract address
    "0xb513bF478caD09db7754A6139616ba5514f3a068", // another contract address
    {from:web3.eth.defaultAccount, gas : 5000000}, function(error, result){
  if(!error){     
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

I am able to deploy my contract in remix and not via web3.js. i have increased the gas limit but nothing works.

The total number of arguments are also correct.
Basically, i have to pass arguments to constructor to deploy the Smart contract. That is why i have used "new"

P.S

```
function Product(bytes32 _name, bytes32 _additionalInformation, 
      address[] _parentProducts, int _lon, int _lat, address _DATABASE_CONTRACT, address _PRODUCT_FACTORY) {
name = _name;
isConsumed = false;
parentProducts = _parentProducts;
additionalInformation = _additionalInformation;

DATABASE_CONTRACT = _DATABASE_CONTRACT;
PRODUCT_FACTORY = _PRODUCT_FACTORY;

Action memory creation;
creation.handler = msg.sender;
creation.description = "Product creation";
creation.lon = _lon;
creation.lat = _lat;
creation.timestamp = now;
creation.blockNumber = block.number;

actions.push(creation);

Database database = Database(DATABASE_CONTRACT);
database.storeProductReference(this);
 }
```

Comment: please add your smart contract constructor code and error log for more clarification.

Comment: @MaheshRajput done

Comment: The 'out of gas' error is most likely misleading. You have at least one error in your code, at `Database database = Database(...)`, where you should create the `Database` instance using `new`. Also, since you haven't posted your `Database` contract, it is impossible to say how it impacts the behavior. For all we know, its constructor might be causing the problem.

Comment: Also, please note that in your deployment code, you should cast the `bytes32` arguments from ascii to hex. The syntax for this is slightly different between web3.js v0.x and web3.js v1.x, so without knowing which version you're using, I cannot tell you which syntax you should apply.

Comment: @goodvibration there is no problem with the contract code orelse i would NOT have been able to deploy on Ropsten or  in any environment via REMIX.
The problem is with web3.js, i am not able to deploy via web3.js

Comment: @goodvibration 
i am passing bytes32
To check the solidity code check this github link https://github.com/dhaileytaha/SupplyChainEthereum/tree/master/contracts

database.sol and product.sol
everything is there